# How to Target Web Parts to an Audience

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

Hi i am new in sharepoint. How to progammatically Target Web Parts to an Audience suggest any answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you notice that there is a gray edit-link below your question? In the future it would be nice if you could use that instead of reposting a question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [link](http://gopika-lasitha.blogspot.com/2010/11/programmatically-set-audience-to.html):

To provide permission to a sharepoint web part for specific SharePoint Group, we have to use AudienceManager as shown below

```
SPWeb currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPSite spSite = currentSite.Site;

SPServiceContext sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(spSite);
AudienceManager am = new AudienceManager(sc);

Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPLimitedWebPartManager mgr = null;
mgr = currentSite.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SitePages" + "/" + page,         
      System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart webPart in mgr.WebParts)
{
     if (webPart.Title == "WebPartTitle")
     {
          //Get the Existing Audience for the Web Part
          string audWebPart = webPart.AuthorizationFilter;
          //If there is no Audience for the Web Part just add it
          if (audWebPart == "")
          {
               webPart.AuthorizationFilter = ";;;;" + NewAudience;
          }
          //If already Audiences are exist for the Web Part then append new Audience
          else
          {
               webPart.AuthorizationFilter = audWebPart + "," + NewAudience;
          }
          mgr.SaveChanges(webPart);
          lblMessage.Text = "Succeeded...";
     }
}
```

If we just set the value for AuthorizationFilter property, then the existing Audiences will be overwritten. 
To avoid it first we have to check whether already audiences exists for that web part. If so we have to append it.

The SharePoint Server 2010 framework requires that three kinds of values be separated by a pair of semicolons (";;"). Multiple values for global audiences and SharePoint groups are delimited by commas, and multiple values for distribution lists are delimited by newline characters ("\n"). Therefore in the above example we used ";;;;" to provide valid string to the AuthorizationFilter property.

Comment: I applied same code but error is occuring. error is-The type or namespace name 'AudienceManager' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) i added namespace Microsoft.Office.Server.Audience; but it is giving error that server is not found in Microsoft.Office namespace

Comment: Thanks for Your reply. my problem has been solved. thankyou so much

Comment: Your welcome! Glad to help.  If this answer did resolve your issue it would be appreciated if you could mark it as the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Is the `AudienceManager am = new AudienceManager(sc);` statement even used? I do not see where `am` is used later in that code fragment.  If not used, it appears that the three preceding lines can also be removed.